# TeamBuild build error: Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:skipInvalid

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a solution created with VS2013 with this projects:

- WebApp (Asp.net mvc5 web app)
- Common (c# library project)

The solution is versioned on server TFS2013.

I Create and edited a build definition for my solution where i want create 2 build using Release and Debug configuration.

I have configured build definition like this [article](https://vosseburchttechblog.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2014/03/20/how-to-apply-web-config-transformations-during-tfs-build/) because i want tranform Web.Config

When i add MSBuild this arguments in my Team Build definition:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False

Now i have this error:

> (PackageUsingManifest target) -> 
>            C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3883,5): error : Web deployment task failed.
>             (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:skipInvalid.)

If i remove the MSBuild argument it works.

**QUESTION**: What's could be configured wrong?

Comment: The error said ''Web deployment task failed'' If you remove the argument `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` and just keep `/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False` what' your build result?

Comment: ASPNETCOMPILER : error 1003: The directory    'C:\Builds\1\TfsPrj\Myproject\bin\Debug\\_PublishedWebsites\WebApp' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that on my local machine there was Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 while on the server TFS there was Visual Studio 2013 RTM (no update).

I resolved with a update of Visual Studio 2013 at last version (Update 5) on server where is installed TFS.

Comment: This is make sense. To make sure the build successful, you should keep your build server environment the same with  your local environment.